# Passing in non-attribute values to Machinist blueprint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, machinist

This is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do...

Suppose I had an object `Person`:

```
Person.blueprint do
  name
  age
end
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
Person.blueprint(:from_birthdate) do
  name
  age { Time.now - birthdate }
end

Person.make(:from_birthdate, :birthdate => 5.years.ago)
```

However, I'm not allowed to pass values into `make` that aren't actual attributes of the `Person` object. Is there a way to pass in an arbitrary object to the blueprint?

Answer (score 0):

You could make an `attr_accessor` for `birthdate`, but that seems a little silly. You might need to just define a separate method:

```
def Person.make_from_birthdate(attributes)
  birthdate = attributes.delete :birthdate
  Person.make attributes.merge(:age => Time.now - birthdate)
end
```

However, storing age is generally a bad practice.  Since age changes with time and birthdate doesn't, you'd normally want to store the birthdate in the DB and calculate age (based on today's date) as necessary.

Comment: I agree that's not a good way to store age. I'm actually doing something different, but the age thing is much easier to explain.

Comment: In the future, please use sample code that is as close to your actual use case as possible. Fake examples tend to lead to poor answers for *actual* use cases.